# How to Change the Color of multiple <TextInput> elements in a <View> at once?

Tags: react-native

My form has a `View` with multiple `<TextInput>` elements. When user clicks on submit button all fields should become `non-editable` which is possible with,

```
<View pointerEvents='none'>
</View>
```

But It can only prevent the user not to edit the field, But doesn't give the appearance of field as it is `disabled`.

Hence, Is there any way to give the `disable` look to all `<TextInput>` elements at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any prop on the View which will help you to give a "disabled" UI. pointerEvents allows you to prevent editing of each component. Infact, TextInput has an editable prop but no disabled prop. Which suggests that there is no in-built visual cue to indicate that the component cannot be edited. The only clue that you have by default is that there is no keyboard appearing when you focus on the item. In short, there is nothing available out-of-the-box to give a disabled visual cue to each of your components.

Answer (score 0):

For the appearance of `<TextInput>` as disabled you need specify the backgroundColor of the `<TextInput>` according to the condition when you make the `<TextInput>` non-editable.

```
state = {
    text:"",
    isEditable:true
}

<TextInput
    editable={this.state.isEditable}
    style={{height: 40, backgroundColor:(this.state.isEditable)?'white':'#EDEEEF'}}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
    value={this.state.text}
/>
```

And on submit button press you can set the `isEditable` to false once all your validation is successful:

```
onSubmit(){

   //Your logic goes here after successful validation set isEditable to false

   this.setState({isEditable:false});
}
```